# What's the most efficient way to turn Gold into Experience?

Tags: dragonvale

I'm getting gold pretty quickly but I'd really like to max out my level. What's the most efficient way to turn gold into XP, in terms of Gold/XP?

The best I can think of is food, since I get XP for buying it, and then I get more for feeding it to dragons, but I don't know how this stacks up to say buying Metal Dragon eggs and hatching them; those give good XP as well, in fact I think it's one point of XP per gold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT

With the race being put into the game this could not be a much better way to change Gold into XP. The race will always cost you 50,000 gold and the reward is random, but hitting even 1.8m in a reward out of 20 tries would average the results of breeding metal dragons listed below. However, I am going to leave the information below as well because there is nothing saying you can not breed metal dragons while running races.

---

Based on the data I could find, raising dragons is the best gold to xp exchange granting a 4 to 1 ratio for **Earth** dragons and a 2 to 1 ratio for **Fire** and **Metal** dragons.

Behold, a chart! (Created with v1.7.2 data)
[image]

The above ratios assume you are not keeping the dragon and are going to sell the dragon as soon as it hatches. It also only contains dragons that can, at this point in time, be purchased directly for gold and raised.

There may be some long game plan you could do with raising farms to raise dragon levels but there is not currently enough information available for me to crunch those numbers to see if it is more efficient to sell a higher level dragon vs the food costs to get it there.

One last note selling and buying dragons every 5 minutes is not the least tedious thing to be doing, but it does cycle through your hatchery pretty well depending on what types of dragons you are attempting to breed.

Comment: Looks like Metal dragons are the only feasible option there, cool that you found the numbers

Comment: Metal will keep you from going insane like as not, but they will also keep your hatchery full for a while.. it will become a balancing act between hatching bred vs bought eggs.

Comment: I'm breeding Rainbow dragons anyway...plenty of time between eggs to hatch Metals

Comment: Growing food + feeding looks to be much less efficient for XP than I expected so this looks like the best solution

Comment: Bear in mind that you're looking at gold per XP but ignoring *time*. Earth and Metal dragon eggs take a long time to hatch.

Comment: @Shadur True. It is done that way because most of these tasks are not exclusive of each other. There is no reason to Not grow plants, build decorations, breed dragons and race all at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a huge treat farm I think sarjin pepper gives a lot of xp and takes a minute to grow. If you have tons of money you should do it. Ps it takes 500,000 gold to grow one.