# What is the best way to earn experience in dragonvale?

Tags: dragonvale

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the most efficient way to turn Gold into Experience?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/61957/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-turn-gold-into-experience)

I would like to know if there anyone has come up with a way to earn experience rather efficiently.

Comment: I'm not really sure this is a duplicate. The other question/answer goes off of the assumption that everyone has excess gold, which isn't always the case. (I, for one, have a hard time saving gold in this game.) Given that there are so many other ways to get XP than just spending gold, I feel this is a broader question that could potentially elicit a pretty useful answer.

Comment: This is a general question about XP, the other is very narrow in it's scope (money → XP).